# Redirect .aspx URL's to non .aspx URL's - using htaccess

Tags: asp.net, .htaccess, redirect

I recently moved my website from a ASP/IIS server to a LINUX/APACHE:

Most of my new URL's looks the same, but without .aspx extension.

OLD: `http://example.com/yankees-news.aspx`
NEW: `http://example.com/yankees-news`

I want search engine users clicking on old URL's/Links to Redirect to new URLs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.aspx$ $1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: I have added this 2 lines to  .htaccess  file.

Its not working.

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.aspx$ $1 [NC,L,R=301]

Comment: Put mine rule first, before RewriteCond